# Proximity based device control panel suggestions

Tags: c#, proximity

I'm writing a control panel that will monitor a few ppl.

I need to know if a certain person enters/leaves an area of the room, You can assume they all have smartphones.

The ppl can login the first time they enter the area, but after that all entering/leaving the area will be done automatically.

I'm looking for a device that will send me their status so I can make a control panel monitoring the areas and the ppl.

Bluetooth/RFID/Security camera style that will be able to send the data back to me (the server). The control panel will be made with C# (its a requirement) so it must synchronize with that.

Anyone have ideas suggestion? even if you don't know of kind of device but can give me ideas.

Comment: This sounds very broad. You might want to try and be more specific as to what your question is.

Comment: I want to know if a phone is in a certain zone in the room. For example Bluetooth sensor that will check every X seconds and send the answer to a server (over the Internet). But it should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a device like iBeacon ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon ) or similar.

With a few of those you should be able to pinpoint the location of their smartphones / bluetooth devices inside your desired area and use then the information provided to monitor their positions.